# Odoo window action button using XML ID

Tags: odoo

In an Odoo view, I can create a button to trigger a specific window action by giving the button a `name` equal to the database identifier for the action. For example:

```xml
<button type="action" name="123">Trigger</button>
```

Will trigger action id `123` when clicked.

Is it possible to accomplish the same thing using the `XML ID` of the action rather than the database ID?

I'm asking because I have created a module full of data files that include view and window actions. The views include a reference to the ID of the window action since they contain buttons to trigger them. However, I don't know the ID's of the window actions until the module is imported, so I can't include them in the views on the initial import.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer:

```xml
<button type="action" name="%(xml_id_of_action)d"></button>
```